# Update control in master page on childpage's postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

The small profile picture in top right corner of the page is part of master page (asp:Image) and will be display on Page_load event.

[image]

In the content page which will be used to update the profile picture, after save button click event fired, how do I update the picture on master page, right now only the big picture of content was updated (because I put the code to update it at the end of Save_button click event). What the the idea here and what steps I should follow?

[image]

Comment: "because I put the code to update it at the end of Save_button click event" Can't you do the same for the "Master page" image?

Comment: Why do you want it in the master page?

Comment: @Hoh I would love to if you can help me LOL, in other words, how to access the control in the master page and change it...?

Comment: Is the update happening via AJAX so that the page isn't refreshing, and that is why you can't change that masterpage image? If so, when the User Account image is updated, just use javascript replace the image source of that masterpage img... at that point its all client side so the fact that it is child/masterpage doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the `MasterType` property in the child page (MasterPage is the class name):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Child1.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Child1" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ MasterType TypeName="MasterPage" %>
```

Then, in the MasterPage, make public any property or field you want the child pages to have access to.

The properties/fields should show up in intellisense in the child pages.

Here is the full code to a MasterPage and how to make an element public:

MasterPage.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:image id="_MyImage" runat="server"></asp:image>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

MasterPage.Master.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public Image MyImage
    {
        get { return _MyImage; }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this but I don't see any intellisense of the <asp:image> in the Master Page, can you demo some code of your idea, for example how to access a label and an image of master Page on Child Pages?

btw I used: *Image newID = (Image)Master.FindControl("imgID");* to basically find the Master Page's  Image on child-page and it worked but I still want to learn your idea.

Comment: Does it compile when using MasterType?  As I recall, it took awhile for the intellisense to 'catch up' to the code.

Comment: It will not built, how do you access, say, asp:image ID="imgProfile" on master page named MainMaster on child page code behind?

Comment: ok so I tried: *MainMaster.imgProfile.ImageUrl = ....* and it says: *...object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property...* AND *...inaccessible due to its protection level...* how do you make img be public in master page so child page can access it?

Answer (score 0):

Try raising an event from the User Control and have the Master Page handle the event.

Here is an example:

http://snippets.surfthru.com/post/ASPNET-Raise-Event-on-Parent-Page-from-User-Control

Comment: URL fails to resolve; Web Archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140515235628/http://snippets.surfthru.com/post/ASPNET-Raise-Event-on-Parent-Page-from-User-Control